# text editing in conventional browser

Tags: richtextbox

Some webpages, such as NEW in yahoo mail, allow editing text in scrollable field (font,fontface and style, alignment, ...) and copy/paste selections using client side scripting that works on most conventional browsers.
I would like to see a complete detailed description of that scripting.

Thanks, Seppe

Answer (score 0):

There are many `RickTextBox` implementations (client and server side) available for free on net, depending on in what language you want you can check the code of the respective plug-in and its detailed description, few to mention here:

- [20 Excellent Free Rich-Text Editors](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/)
- [Editor for ASP.NET MVC](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/editor)
- [Client Side (jQuery & JavaScript based)](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)